# Zabbix web interface says Zabbix server is offline when failing over to passive node

Tags: high-availability, zabbix, pacemaker, cman

Two Zabbix 2.4 servers using CentOS 6.6 with an external MySQL DB, both servers are configured to connect to this DB when they are running.

I followed a combination of [Zabbit High Availability guide](https://www.zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/howto/high_availability_on_Centos_6.x) and the [Quickstart from Clusterlabs](http://clusterlabs.org/quickstart-redhat-6.html). I think I have finished the setup since when I do a failover (node1 to node2) the virtual IP is assigned to Active node and the zabbix-server service also starts running.

However, the web interface says Zabbix server is not running. I don't see any errors or warnings in the log file. When I fail back to node1, everything is fine and web ui says zabbix server is running.

```
*********** This is the node where Zabbix server is fine
[root@zabbixserver3 ~]# netstat -ntap | grep 10051
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10051               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      14880/zabbix_server
tcp        0      0 10.99.99.93:38034           10.99.99.93:10051           TIME_WAIT   -       
tcp        0      0 10.99.99.93:38032           10.99.99.93:10051           TIME_WAIT   -       
tcp        0      0 10.99.99.93:38022           10.99.99.93:10051           TIME_WAIT   -       
tcp        0      0 10.99.99.93:38024           10.99.99.93:10051           TIME_WAIT   -       
tcp        0      0 10.99.99.93:38036           10.99.99.93:10051           TIME_WAIT   -       
tcp        0      0 :::10051                    :::*                        LISTEN      14880/zabbix_server
```

```
*********** This is the node where Zabbix server show not running

[root@zabbixserver2 zabbix]# netstat -ntap | grep 10051
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10051               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      31568/zabbix_server
tcp        0      0 :::10051                    :::*                        LISTEN      31568/zabbix_server
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. It was a very elusive typo in /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php

I got one character wrong in server name!